# Reason for adding jar file in lib folder for jsp?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Why we need to add jar file in lib instead of build path for jsp ,what is the difference ?

[image: like this]

Comment: Perhaps one works, the other doesn't? Because it was designed that way? What is your real question?

Answer (score 0):

JAR files copied into the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of a web project are added to the buildpath of that project. The contents of the JAR file will appear in the IDE and they will be available at build and deployment for that single project only.  Default `/WEB-INF/lib` directory contains JAR files used by the Web application, including JSP tag libraries.This is the place where  Servlet Containter expects to find JAR files. Also remember that should be `WEB-INF/lib`, not `WEB-INF/LIB` since Java is case sensitive, but that don't matter since most IDEs  create it  automatically.